# SML/NJ using CM.make: "Error: illegal character"

Tags: sml, smlnj, cm

I'm trying to compile the following program from Shipman's [Unix System Programming with Standard ML](http://mlton.org/References.attachments/Shipman02.pdf#page=32):

```
structure Main=
struct

    fun main(arg0, argv) =
    (
        case argv of
          [] => ()
        | (first::rest) =>
        (
            print first;
            app (fn arg => (print " "; print arg)) rest;
            print "\n"
        );

        OS.Process.success
    )

    val _ = SMLofNJ.exportFn("echo", main)
end
```

My .cm file looks like:

```
group is
    $/basis.cm
    echo.sml
```

When I run `CM.make "echo.sml";` I get the following error message:

```
gotchops@gotchops-vm:~/Documents/USPwSML/Ch2/echo$ CM_ROOT=echo.cm sml
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.80 [built: Fri Sep 16 22:36:30 2016]
- CM.make "echo.sml";
[autoloading]
[library $smlnj/cm/cm.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/internal/cm-sig-lib.cm is stable]
[library $/pgraph.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/internal/srcpath-lib.cm is stable]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/(basis.cm):basis-common.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
[scanning echo.sml]
echo.sml:7.11 Error: illegal character: [
echo.sml:7.12 Error: illegal character: ]
echo.sml:1.2-1.16 Error: syntax error: deleting  STRUCTURE ML_ID
echo.sml:6.9 Error: syntax error: inserting  RPAREN
echo.sml:8.17-8.19 Error: syntax error: deleting  COLON COLON
echo.sml:11.14 Error: syntax error: replacing  LPAREN with  RPAREN
echo.sml:11.32-11.34 Error: syntax error: deleting  FILE_NATIVE
echo.sml:11.47 Error: syntax error: inserting  LPAREN
echo.sml:12.16-12.19 Error: syntax error: replacing  FILE_NATIVE with LPAREN
echo.sml:13.10 Error: syntax error: inserting  LPAREN
echo.sml:17.30-17.35 Error: syntax error: deleting  FILE_NATIVE
echo.sml:19.1 Error: syntax error found at EOF
val it = false : bool
```

However, when I run `use "echo.sml";` from the toplevel I can compile just fine. Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're just calling CM on the wrong file. It should be called on the `.cm` file, not the `.sml` file. Since CM is looking for CM syntax, not SML syntax, it throws syntax errors back at you.

From the new version of the CM manual [[pdf](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/CM/new.pdf)]:

> ### 2.3    Invoking CM
>
> Once a library has been set up as shown in the example above, one can load it into a running interactive session by invoking function `CM.make`. If the name of the library’s description file is, say, `fb.cm`, then one would type
>
> ```
> CM.make "fb.cm";
> ```

Using CM this way, I was able to compile your example without any problem, and then run the program like so:

```
$ sml @SMLload=echo.x86-darwin a b c d e
a b c d e
```

(Following the [documentation on SML_OF_NJ.exportFn](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/SMLofNJ/pages/smlnj.html#SIG:SML_OF_NJ.exportFn:VAL)).

Comment: Please don't feel silly! I only worked this out for myself because I saw your question right when I was making my first attempt to compile an SML executable. You provided the test case and posed the problematic, presenting me everything I needed to figure out this last step. And now we both know how to compile SML executables in SML/NJ (and also why we should probably learn how to use MLton instead ;P :) ).